# Rails STDOUT logs are not coming in kubectl logs and datadog log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, datadog

We have set logger as STDOUT in the rails configuration.

```
  config.log_level = :info
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

We are expecting these logs in kubectl logs as well as datadog logs but STDOUT is not showing up there. We tried below code to test it.

```
def method_name
  system('echo testing logging') - this shows up in kubectl/datadog logs
  Rails.logger.info('STDOUT - testing logging') - this does not show up in kubectl/datadog log
end
```

Comment: Does it work on your local development environment?

Comment: yes, we tried to call this method from rails console.


irb(main):005:0> def method_name
irb(main):006:1>   system('echo testing logging')
irb(main):007:1>   Rails.logger.info('STDOUT - testing logging')
irb(main):008:1> end
=> :method_name
irb(main):009:0> method_name
testing logging
I, [2022-07-11T05:41:42.543433 #173782]  INFO -- : STDOUT - testing logging
=> true

Comment: I dont find these logs in docker logs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the default config and make sure to set the environment variable `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true`, for your deployment/replica set, and in production mode (`RAILS_ENV=production`). (In dev mode it always logs to console per default).

Actually, the official rails docker images used to have that set, but the newer recommended ruby docker images - of course - do not have Rails specific environment variables set.

(more: search for *RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT* in the [release notes here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/5_0_release_notes.html), and see [PR here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23734))

Answer (score 0):

We have changed the logger setting to output the logs to container file descriptor.

Reference: https://blog.eq8.eu/til/ruby-logs-and-puts-not-shown-in-docker-container-logs.html

Comment: this is only a workaround... take a look at other suggestions!